# Errno 11004 getaddrinfo failed error in connecting to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am trying to use the boto [(ver 2.43.0)](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html) library in Python to connect to S3, but I keep getting `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004]` when I try to do this:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

access_key = 'accesskey_here'
secret_key = 'secretkey_here'
conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('s3://diap.prod.us-east-1.mybucket/')
print("success!")
```

I can connect to and access folders in `mybucket` using AWS CLI by using a command like this in Windows:

```
> aws s3 ls s3://diap.prod.us-east-1.mybucket/
<list of folders in mybucket will be here>
```

or using software like CloudBerry or S3Browser.

Is there something that I am doing wrong here to access S3 bucket and folders properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_bucket()` expects a bucket name.

```
get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=True, headers=None)
```

Try:

```
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
```

If it doesn't work, show the full stack trace.

{**Update**]: There is a bug in boto library for bucket names with dot. Update your boto config

```
[s3]
calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
```

Or

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, OrdinaryCallingFormat

conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key, calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. When I entered the bucket name like this:
>>> mybucket = conn.get_bucket('diap.prod.us-east-1.mybucket')
I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
....
  File "C:\Users\phyo.thiha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\ssl.py", line 296, in match_hostname
    % (hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames))))
ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'diap.prod.us-east-1.target.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'

Comment: I am sorry. Your bucket name has `us-east-1` in it?

Comment: yes...I was able to use that name, `diap.prod.us-east-1.mybucket`, to log in using AWS CLI or CloudBerry...

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Adding the `OrdinaryCallingFormat()` in the parameter works!! I couldn't believe there is no mentioning of that in the doc or anywhere... Maybe Boto doc for 2.43 (the one that I linked in my question above) is outdated??

Comment: It is a bug in Boto. You should switch to Boto3.

Comment: Yes! I just switched to `boto3`. In case anyone in the future is curious, we can get the list of files/folders in an S3 bucket by doing something like this:

====
from boto3 import client
conn = client('s3')
for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='diap.prod.us-east-1.mybucket', Prefix='folder_prefix/')['Contents']:
  print(key['Key'])
====